# selenium opens multiple windows because there are multiple instances

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i'm pretty new to selenium and programming in general so this may be an easy fix.  i know this is opening multiple browser windows because i'm defining multiple instances (loginPage and topNavigationMenu).  is there a way to prevent opening multiple browsers?

-----loginTest.java file-----

```
public class loginTest {

loginPage login = new loginPage();
topNavigationMenu navMenu = new topNavigationMenu();

String url = "http://www.url.com";

@Test
public void loginSuccessfully()
{
    String email = "username";
    String password = "password";

    login.loadSignInPage(url);
    login.verifySignInPage();

    login.enterLoginCredentials(email,password);
    login.clickSignInButton();

    navMenu.verifyNavigationMenu();

    driver.close();
}
```

-----loginPage.java file-----
public class loginPage {

```
private WebDriver driver;

public loginpage(WebDriver driver)  // this is the line with that error (line 33)
{
    this.driver = driver;
}


public void loadSignInPage(String url)
{
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

...etc...(more methods)
```

}

Comment: _this is opening multiple browser windows because i'm defining multiple instances (loginPage and topNavigationMenu)_  Is it really? Opening browser windows depends on instances of WebDriver. If you want just one window, simply do not instantiate multiple instances of it. If you're unsure, please post the code of `loginPage` and  `topNavigationMenu`

Comment: Can you post code for opening browser think that will be located or called in loginPage method.

Comment: do you need more info or is the answer below what you are looking for? If so, accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing the code of `loginPage` or `topNavigationMenu` I think you have put the instantation of the WebDriver in the constructor of `loginPage` and `topNavigationMenu`. Make the constructors like this.

```
public class LoginPage {

  private WebDriver driver;

  public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

}

public class TopNavigationMenu {

  private WebDriver driver;

  public TopNavigationMenu(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

}
```

Please delete the method `closeBrowser` because closing the browser should happen in your test. Then in your test you instantiate the driver.

```
public class LoginTest { 

@Test
public void loginSuccessfully() {
  WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
  LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);

  String email = "username";
  String password = "password";

  login.loadSignInPage(url);
  login.verifySignInPage();
  login.enterLoginCredentials(email,password);
  login.clickSignInButton();

  new TopNavigationMenu(driver).verifyNavigationMenu();

  driver.quit();
}
```

Also, consider using setUp and tearDown methods. I cannot see whether you are using JUnit or TestNG so without that info, I cannot help you with that.

---

### Edit after the update of the question

In your update your class is called `loginPage` but your constructor does not match the name, it's called `loginpage`. So change your constructor to this.

```
public class loginPage {

  private WebDriver driver;

  public loginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey @david-baak.  I changed my constructor and I get a "Error:(33, 12) java: invalid method declaration; return type required" for this "public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)"

Comment: @p hong  Could you post your code? Makes it easier to fix the issue

Comment: added code in original message.  let me know if you need more details.  thanks!